# Firemonkey in Delphi XE5. How to create popup menu for my icon in the tray?

Tags: delphi, winapi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Noticed this - [FireMonkey tray icon with a menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930831/firemonkey-tray-icon-with-a-menu)

But this topic didn't help at all.

I did a feature that my program can minimize to the tray (a corner that close to the clock) but i can't understand how to execute a popup menu for it (that could appear by right clicking on the tray icon). I tried much examples but nothing works.

Here's my code:

```
unit MainCode;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Edit, FMX.Objects, FMX.ListBox, WinApi.ShellApi, WinApi.Windows, WinApi.Messages, FMX.Platform.Win, FMX.Menus, FMX.Platform;

const
      WM_ICONTRAY = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItem1: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);

private
  TrayWnd: HWND;
  TrayIconData: TNotifyIconData;
  TrayIconAdded: Boolean;
  procedure TrayWndProc(var Message: TMessage);

public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrayWnd := AllocateHWnd(TrayWndProc);
  with TrayIconData do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf();
    Wnd:= TrayWnd; // was before Wnd:= FmxHandleToHWND(self.Handle);
    uID:= 0;
    uFlags:= NIF_MESSAGE + NIF_ICON + NIF_TIP;
    uCallbackMessage:= WM_ICONTRAY;
    hIcon:= GetClassLong(FmxHandleToHWND(self.Handle), GCL_HICONSM);
    szTip:= 'Hearthspinner';
  end;

  if not TrayIconAdded then
    TrayIconAdded := Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @TrayIconData);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TrayIconAdded then
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @TrayIconData);
  DeallocateHWnd(TrayWnd);
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;
```

The code above works fine. Next code doesn't work:

```
procedure TForm1.TrayWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var P: TPoint;
begin
  if Message.MSG = WM_ICONTRAY then
  begin

    case Message.LParam of
      WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
      begin
        GetCursorPos(P);
        PopupMenu1.Popup(P.X,P.Y);
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(TrayWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

Comment: Why are you not using TTrayIcon? It has a PopupMenu property

Comment: @jason I guess because it's a vcl component

Comment: Right. There's no such component in Firemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong window handle. Instead of

```
Wnd:= FmxHandleToHWND(self.Handle);
```

you need

```
Wnd:= TrayWnd;
```

You should also remove `message WM_ICONTRAY` from `TrayWndProc`. It serves no purpose in the context of FMX and just confuses.

Comment: Thank you! I also deleted `if Message.MSG = WM_ICONTRAY` condition and now it works! But now also I have an odd another problem: The popup menu appers behind the menu with tray icons (on Windows 7).

I did some screenshots to explain what I mean:
http://i.imgur.com/mYmjT3a.png
http://i.imgur.com/NQsxgWV.png

How can I fix it?

Comment: Yet another bug: If tray icon appers not in the menu but near the clock ([like this](http://i.imgur.com/yqK2FJp.png)) then right clicking on it doesn't work at all (menu doesn't appers) :(

Comment: Deleting `if Message.MSG = WM_ICONTRAY` is the wrong thing to do. I can't help you if you do that.

Comment: I run my program without deleting this and nothing worked again. Then I tried to delete this condition and something changed. If you think that's wrong thing that i did I always can bring the code back (and I have already done this). But what do you suggest then? Whithout deleting `if Message.MSG = WM_ICONTRAY` nothing works (again). Btw sorry for my english. That's not my native language.

Comment: It's very hard to help when I cannot see a complete program, and the only diagnosis is "it doesn't work".

Comment: It all works perfectly apart from the popup menu. Don't know why that fails.

Comment: Something to do with FMX. I don't know enough about FMX, so I can't help any more.

Comment: I changed the code in the topic. You can now look at full code if you still want to help me. If you've already done, very thank you anyway!

Comment: I can't help. Know nothing about fmx menus. The point is the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` code fires.

Comment: I'm curious. Why did you accept? I've not solved the problem with the menus.